# Rails 6 Devise test helpers without RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

Devise test helpers with Rails 6 without Rspec doesn't seem to work. Here is the code, any idea why it might be getting errors?

Controller:

```
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

  def index
    @vehicles = Vehicle.all
  end

  def new
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new
  end
end
```

test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
end
```

user fixture:

```
valid_user:
  first_name: "Toseef"
  last_name: "zafar"
  email: "exampleuser@gmail.com"
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, '12345678') %>
```

controller test:

```
require "test_helper"
class VehiclesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should be able to get to new form page" do
    sign_in users(:valid_user)
    get new_vehicles_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Failure:
VehiclesControllerTest#test_should_be_able_to_get_to_new_form_page [/test/controllers/vehicles_controller_test.rb:12]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>
Response body: <html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>


rails test test/controllers/vehicles_controller_test.rb:9
```

Also, I don't know why it would point to http://www.example.com

Comment: You asked this exact same question yesterday and deleted it.

Comment: yes, not getting any responses, tried to refresh the post to see if I can get help

Comment: you received a number of comments , which you did not incorporate into the post

Comment: didn't know I could do that, will look into it, have you ever had a similar issue that I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

The devise user model has got `confirmable` hence when we do `sign_in users(:valid_user)` devise creates a user but because the user is not confirmed (i.e. no confirmation email link clicking is involved) when we go to a secured URL it takes us back to login because user hasn't confirmed through clicking on the link from the email.

The solution to this is to set `confirmed_at` value to `Time.now` before `sign_in`

e.g.

```
@user = users(:valid_user)
@user.confirmed_at = Time.now
sign_in @user
```

after doing that the tests passed! :)